# Is there a Java library for decoding php session data?

Tags: java, php, session

I am working on an application that mixes php and Java. I need to inject some values into the php session through Java, but to do this I need to be able to parse the values of the php session into a set. Is there a library that will let me undo in Java what session_encode does in php?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460002/how-to-pass-a-session-between-tomcat-and-php

Comment: not really, my question is more specific and is not solved in the question you linked.

Comment: Please be aware of the fact that the PHP session module uses a slightly different way to serialize data from the way serialize() works - it is not equivalent to serialize($_SESSION) but some kind of foreach($_SESSION as $k=>$v) { $result .= $k.':'.serialize($v); } which is for historic reasons (register_globals)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure your PHP environment to store the session data in WWDX format
http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.serialize-handler

```
session.serialize_handler defines the name of the handler which is used to 
  serialize/deserialize data. Currently, a PHP internal format (name php or php_binary) 
  and WDDX are supported (name wddx). WDDX is only available, 
  if PHP is compiled with WDDX support. Defaults to php.`
```

About WDDX:

`The Web Distributed Data Exchange, or WDDX, is a free, open XML-based technology that allows Web applications created with any platform to easily exchange data with one another over the Web.`

and the Java WDDX Parser available via googling :)
http://www.google.com.ua/search?q=java+wddx+parser

Ofcourse this solution is more complex than just write simple parser class – the PHP session format is really simple.

Comment: No, but it's format looks pretty simple: `type`:`length`:`data`;